# Why do getNewValue() and getOldValue() are deprecated in ListEvent class in Glazed Lists?

Tags: java, glazedlists

I would like to observe list changes in `EventList` with [`ListEvent`](https://svn.java.net/svn/glazedlists~svn/tags/glazedlists-1_9_0/www/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/event/ListEvent.html) in Glazed Lists.

Surprisingly, methods [`getNewValue()`](https://svn.java.net/svn/glazedlists~svn/tags/glazedlists-1_9_0/www/api/ca/odell/glazedlists/event/ListEvent.html#getNewValue%28%29) also also as `getOldValue()` are deprecated without no any compos explanation.

Why?

How to know, which elements are added or removed then?

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal because deprecation is reserved for old code/approaches which are being retired. In this instance it would have better to annotate as "experimental" because what the developer is trying to say is "be careful, this is new and may change. Don't rely on it yet."

See the description in the docs (I've emphasised the key line):

> In the future, ListEvent will provide even more information about the
>   list changes to be more self-contained:
>
> for deletes, it will provide the deleted element with getOldValue()
>   for inserts, it will provide the inserted element with getNewValue()
>   for updates, it will provide the old and new element with
>   getOldValue() and getNewValue() **The methods are currently marked as
>   deprecated and should not be used yet, because the implementation is a
>   work in progress**.

I don't think Javadoc has any annotation for experimental code, so the developer has chosen to use deprecation to warn users of the library.

Comment: Firstly your question asks about why they are labelled as deprecated - my reply answered that question. As to your follow up question: I would think it sensible to experiment with those methods to see if it behaves well within your application. There's no other option within the API to give you this information. It's clear from the documentation that they intend to finesse these methods and declare them robust in v2.0. They first landed in v1.8. The devs are simply covering themselves by saying it's experimental. I've never used them but I suspect you'll get decent results.